# Conditionally rewrite request url based on referer - Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, hashicorp-vault

What I am trying to achive; is when the request coming from `http://<ip>/vault/ui/` (referer in the request header) and it includes the `http://<ip>/v1/*` endpoint, to be rewriten or redirected to `http://<ip>/vault/v1/`

can someone please help me to solve this issue?

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf**

```
upstream command_center_vault {
   server command-center-0.blinchik.io:28200;  
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


location /vault/ {

     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
   
     proxy_pass "http://command_center_vault/vault/";
     proxy_redirect /ui/ /vault/ui/;
  }

location /vault/v1/ {

     proxy_pass "http://command_center_vault/v1/";

  }

}
```

**Headers**

[image]

---

## Update

A little bit more context, the overarching architecture looks as in the picture below.

[image]

the configuration of nginx server in the private subnet looks like this:

**private subnet nginx**

```
upstream consul_server {

   server brain-consul-server-0.blinchik.io:8500;
   server brain-consul-server-1.blinchik.io:8500;
   server brain-consul-server-2.blinchik.io:8500;
   
 }

upstream vault_server {

   server brain-vault-server-0.blinchik.io:8200;
   server brain-vault-server-1.blinchik.io:8200;

}


server {

   listen 28500;
   listen [::]:28500;

   location /consul/ {

       proxy_pass "http://consul_server";
       sub_filter_once off;
       sub_filter_types application/javascript text/html;
       sub_filter "/v1/" "/consul_v1/";

   }

   location /consul_v1/ {
       proxy_pass "http://consul_server/v1/";
   }
}

server {

   listen 28200;
   listen [::]:28200;

   location /vault/ {

       proxy_pass "http://vault_server/";

       port_in_redirect off;

       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

       proxy_redirect /ui/ /vault/ui/;
       sub_filter_once off;
       sub_filter '<head>' '<head><base href="/vault/">';
       sub_filter '"/ui/' '"ui/';

       #inspired by this repo https://github.com/Folcky/hashicorp-vault-and-nginx


   }

   location /v1/ {
          proxy_pass "http://vault_server/v1/";
   }

}
```

**public subnet nginx**

```
upstream command_center_vault {
   server command-center-0.blinchik.io:28200;  
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


location /vault/ {

     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
   
     proxy_pass "http://command_center_vault/vault/";
     proxy_redirect /ui/ /vault/ui/;
  }

location /vault/v1/ {

     proxy_pass "http://command_center_vault/v1/";

  }

}
```

the consul part works fine. if I change in the public subnet configuration the location of `/vault/v1/` to `/v1/` then it works as well. But the problem that other products that I intend to add it to the reverse proxy (like Nomad) also uses the `/v1/` path and in this case there will be a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should work (must be placed at the `server` context outside any locations:

```
if ($http_referer ~ /vault/ui) {
    rewrite ^/v1(/.*) /vault/v1$1 last;
}
```

You can make regex pattern more strict including `//<ip>` or `https?://<ip>` parts.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are the MVP of nginx question on SO :) 
I updated the question to give more context. I've tried your suggestion and I couldn't make it work yet, will try some variation again. if you feel there is a bettere appraoch than I am using now, will be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: Tried to simulate this with `curl` for debugging purposes, it seems that you need to use `last` flag instead of `break` (which makes surprise for me too - I thought that `break` would work as I expected). Try the updated one please. Yes, I understand now why are you using two `location` blocks.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Did try to change it in the private nginx, public nginx, and both of them at same time. The request URI somehow not changing no matter what I am doing. I decided at the end to serve the two endpoints over different ports.